# Internal SSD not detected in boot or lsblk

Tags: boot, hardware, ssd, troubleshooting, kernel-panic

I had a Linux mint system which was working fine until it froze and the "safe restart" of alt+Sysreq+REISUB didn't work, so I had to hard shutdown.

After this the bootable SSD stopped getting detected at boot, even as a storage device.

I bought a new SSD - it was detected the first time as storage, but the second time it stopped showing in boot. I tried lsblk or fdisk -l with live USB but it failed to show.

The live USB works fine so the motherboard is fine, the data cables should be fine too as before the system froze there was no such issue. What other problem can there be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the recent years, there seems to have been a fairly large batch of bad SATA data cables on the market.

Initially they seem fine, but something (an error in chemical composition?) causes them to age and degrade rapidly. Once aged, moving or bending the cables may make the failure happen quicker.

Because of this, I would not be so quick to trust the cables just because "they used to work fine before". That's just it: they'll work fine, until they no longer won't. Also, replacing the data cable is probably the cheapest thing to try, so it would make sense to do it first.

Another possibility would be a bad controller on the motherboard, but that would most likely be either a hardware bug (so would have been present since new, and later drivers might improve things by implementing a workaround) or a hardware failure (requiring either an add-on card to replace the failing controller, or motherboard replacement).